# Discrete rejection-sampling Monte Carlo with Python

Tags: python, sampling, random, montecarlo

I am using python to use the rejection-acceptance method to sample a discrete MC distribution. Since the curve resembles a [power law](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG3MT.png), I decided to set a simple envelope around it (at x=77) to make the code faster. The code does not perform as expected, though, as it is shown for the figure with a simple rectangle over the entire area, compared to the envelope: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSTfi.png)

x is data.rank, between 0-5000
y is data.freq

Can anyone spot anything wrong with the code? The output of both histograms should be equal. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                        

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import pandas as pd

# Read data
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Rejection-sampling MC (with envelope function gx at rank=77)
N = 1000
M = 1.0001
cutoff = 77
gx = np.ones(cutoff) * max(data['freq'])
gx = np.append( gx, np.ones(len(data['rank'])-cutoff) * data['freq'][cutoff-1] )
histx = []
while N > 0: 
    rx = random.randint(0,len(gx)-1)
    ry = random.uniform(0,1)
    if ry < data['freq'][rx]/(M*gx[rx]):
        histx.append(rx)
        N += -1
plt.hist(histx, bins=100, histtype='stepfilled', color='b',label='Enveloped (Fast)')

# Rejection-sampling MC (with envelope function gx at rank=77)
N2 = 1000
histy = []
while N2 > 0: 
    rx2 = random.randint(0,len(gx)-1)
    ry2 = random.uniform(0,max(data['freq']))
    if ry2 < data['freq'][rx2]:
        histy.append(rx2)
        N2 += -1
plt.hist(histy, bins=100, histtype='stepfilled', color='r', alpha=0.5, label='Normal (Slow)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are different samplings

In the second case, you effectively have

```
ry2 = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
if ry2 < data['freq'][rx2]/max(data['freq']):
    accept
```

In the first case you have

```
ry = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
if ry < data['freq'][rx]/gx[rx]:
    accept
```

Where `gx[rx]` is not equal to `max(data['freq'])`, you'll have a difference

Some advices: try to always use U(0,1) rng call, easier to spot, replace or alter rng. And second, in MC performance (well, after correctness) are of utmost importance, try to compute things like `max(data['freq'])` or `len(gx)` once outside the main loop

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestions. I am still confused about it. Using "envelopes" should be a reliable method to sample the same curve, like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm. This: http://imgur.com/PNx0XzM is what I am trying to achieve. I was also thinking of computing MC in log space to speed things up, but I was stuck on that, too. Is it a problem that the distribution is discrete?

Comment: No, discrete is not a problem, see update for proposed solution

Comment: Will add more in a few hours, sorry for a delay